# Escaping a question mark on the MySQL CLI

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

How do you escape a question mark character in a string on the MySQL CLI?

There are many methods to avoid having to escape characters, but from an ease-of-use perspective I would quite like to do some `SELECT` statements containing `LIKE` queries, some of which contain question marks and the usual `\?` does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LIKE` doesn't use `?`. `LIKE` uses `%` and `_`.

Comment: Same question with a `WHERE =` then.

Comment: `=` doesn't use *any* wildcards.

Comment: I am looking for the string `<a href="/about?param=value">` in a CMS. Performing `SELECT uid FROM cms_table WHERE html LIKE '%/about%'` works, however `SELECT uid FROM cms_table WHERE html LIKE '%/about?%'` doesn't. I cannot seem to escape the question mark and make it part of the statement. The same thing happens when using a plain `WHERE =`.

Comment: Thank you! There is something weird going on with this database, I'll look at character encodings...